# Open office document templates as new document?

Tags: list, word, document-template

In a document list my customer stores word document templates with appropriate file types `[.dot | .dotx | .dotm]`. When a user access these documents, the familiar dialogue box opens with the question to open the document in Read Only or Check Out and Edit.

[image]

But my customer wants a different behavior. She wants the document opened as a new (macro enabled) document as if the word template were opened in Windows Explorer. The customer isn’t fond of using the ribbons “Open with Windows Explorer” option.

**How do I change the behavior of the document list, to open document templates as new document?**

- SharePoint Server 2010
- Office Web Apps is not installed
- Microsoft Word 2007 is default client software for handling documents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you mean by "She wants the document opened as a new (macro enabled) document as if the word template were opened in Windows Explorer", but what I think you need is Content Types.

Create a custom Content Type (based on the Document content type as the parent) for each document template you want to have. Then in the Content Type settings page, go to Advanced Settings - you will see an option to upload a template file for the content type. Upload your .dotx or whatever.

Then in your library settings page, go to Advanced, and enable Content Types on the document library. Back in the library settings page, under Content Types, add your custom content types you have created.

Your users will then be able to create new documents in the library based on your templates, simply by using the New Document button. Hope that solves your problem?

[image]

Comment: Not quite, but I'll try to convince her that this is the way to do it. Basically she wants SharePoint to act as Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same functionality as the new document link in a more familiar "Windows Explorer" type of way by instead of clicking "New Document" offer a link set up like this:

```
ms-word:nft|u|TEMPLATE URL HERE|s|SAVE LOCATION HERE
```

Example:

```
ms-word:nft|u|http://siteurl/documents/templatename.dotx|s|C:\
```

more info on the uri scheme: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx